# stability of the equilibrium at the $\bf{x}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system $\bf{\dot{x}}$=$A$$\bf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R^6}$. You  are  given  that  the  null-space  of $A$ has dimension 2 and the stable subspace of $A$ has dimension 2 and that is an eigenvalue of A Is this information sufficient to infer the stability of the equilibrium at the origin?

## Solution

We see that $i$ we have $Re[i]=0$ with algebraic multiplicity 2. Thus the $rank(A-iI)=6-2=4$.
But I am not sure if this is sufficient to ensure stability of the equilibrium at the origin.

Comment: $A$ could have 3 eigenvalues at zero with one Jordan block of dimension two in which case you have an unbounded solution starting from a point arbitrarily close to the origin. What do you mean by $\operatorname{re} i = 0$, what has that got to do with it?

Comment: I think Victoria was trying to use this theorem http://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearSystems/Sample/Lect_7.pdf @copper.hat

Comment: The answer is that you can find an $A$ that is stable (Lyapunov) or an $A$ that is not stable. Hence you cannot determine stability at the origin.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'stable subspace'?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is not because there could be an attractor that capture the trajectory outside the equilibrium. If somehow the state of the system gets into this attractor, it is impossible to get out.